# Is possible to set background for LinearLayout from the Activity file?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="@color/blue"
android:gravity="center">
```

Is possible to set color from my Activity file?

For example I can do that for a button:

```
ImageButton x = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
x.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can  do it by

```
public class MainActivity {
   private LinearLayout ll;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(...) {
      super.onCreate(...);
      setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);
      ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_id);

      // You can set Background Color for your Linear Layout
      ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
      // You can set Image Also
      ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imagename);
 }
}
```

In XML file :

```
    <LinearLayout 
            android:id="+@id/linear_layout_id"
            android:width = "fill_parent"
            android:height = "fill_parent"
            android:orientation = "vertical"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm there is also setter for LinearLayout

```
setBackgroundColor()
```

Is inherited from the View class

Comment: But how can I obtain LiniarLayout object in my Activity class?

Comment: The same way as you obtain ImageButton in your example. I was thinking that you know that. Look at ADR answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just like you did it for the button you can do the same for the the LinearLayout also. Give you Linearlayout an id and set the color:-

```
((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_test)).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```